# Upload Profile Photo

Tags: bug, profile-page

I am trying to change my Profile Photo in AskUbuntu, but I cannot. Everytime I go to the Edit Profile tag > click Change Picture > Click Upload new Picture > Upload a new Picture(.jpeg file) , still nothing happens. The identicon picture seems to stick around and there's apparently no way to change the default picture. Anyone out there knows how to change the profile picture? Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is finicky -> upload the picture -> save . If it is not working, try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `png` file and use a small one.

**That's it!  ;-)**